# google maps empty in one emulator and not in another flutter android

Tags: flutter, google-maps, android-emulator

I am working on an app with google maps and flutter.
Until yesterday I was able to see the maps in android emulator (Pixel 6a).
After running `flutter upgrade` this morning, the maps is just empty.

[image]

It is still working on my device. I have also tested with Pixel 7 emulator and it is working too.
Any idea why the Pixel 6a is not working anymore?
I have uninstall and re-install the app with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I have restarted my computer and it is working again.